# Why does a component re-render if props are equal

Tags: reactjs

I created a simple react app and checked the app for re-renders with why-did-you-update library and it shows unnecessary re-renders and how to prevent these re-renders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components will get re-rendered if their props change, or if their parent has been re-rendered. It's possible that you have update the props or state of a parent component. React provides a lifecycle function called shouldComponentUpdate to deal with unnecessary renders. It is quicker and easier to implement if you use immutable data for your props since you can simply do an equality check between new props and old props to see if there was any change. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate and https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html